# How to put my map between my menu and my footer

Tags: html, css

In one of my project I need to put a map between two div:

- one is on top and is my menu (his size can change with some jQuery)
- and one on the bottom which is my footer with some link

Also soon I'll put a menu on the left of my screen, so I wanted to know how can I make my map take the remaining space under my menu and over my footer?

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.main_menu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #358ef3;
    height: 9rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

#mapcontainer {
    background-color: red;
}

footer ul {
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: center;
}

footer {
    color: white;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #3368ff;
}

footer nav {
    vertical-align: center;
}

footer a:link, a:visited {
    padding-left: 0rem;
    padding-right: 0rem;
    background-color: #3368ff;
    color: #3368ff;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 0;
    transition: border-radius 2s, background-color 2s, padding-left 2s, padding-right 2s, color 2s;
}

footer a:hover, a:active {
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    background-color: #20f4e7;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_menu">
  <p>
    here is my nav menu which can close and open and has a form
  </p>
</div>
<div id="mapcontainer">
  <p>
  here will be a map
  </p>
</div>
<footer>
    <nav>
        <ul class="importantlinks">
            <li><a href="#">here is my footer</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need for that to add some `css` rules to your body (that is probably the parent of your footer and `#mapcontainer`). Using `flex-box` with the `flex-grow` property do the trick:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;           /* <-- height of the screen */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#mapcontainer {
    background-color: red;
    flex-grow: 1;          /* <--extend the div to next element */
}

footer ul {
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: center;
}

footer {
    color: white;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #3368ff;
}

footer nav {
    vertical-align: center;
}

footer a:link, a:visited {
    padding-left: 0rem;
    padding-right: 0rem;
    background-color: #3368ff;
    color: #3368ff;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 0;
    transition: border-radius 2s, background-color 2s, padding-left 2s, padding-right 2s, color 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_menu">
  <p>
    here is my nav menu wich can close and open and has a form
  </p>
</div>
<div id="mapcontainer">
  <p>
  here will be a map
  </p>
</div>
<footer>
    <nav>
        <ul class="importantlinks">
            <li><a href="#">here is my footer</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</footer>
```

Comment: it dosen't work on my web site for some strange reason the map is over all of my web site

Comment: Can you create and share a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with your entire code to see where the problem is ?

Comment: here it is but I use leaftlet for my map so I couldn't put it in JsFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/lolozen/Le38mjyb/21/

Answer (score -1):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main_menu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #358ef3;
  height: 9rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

#mapcontainer {
  background-color: red;
  top: 9rem;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 18px;
}

footer ul {
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: center;
}

footer {
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #3368ff;
}

footer nav {
  vertical-align: center;
}

footer a:link,
a:visited {
  padding-left: 0rem;
  padding-right: 0rem;
  background-color: #3368ff;
  color: #3368ff;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: border-radius 2s, background-color 2s, padding-left 2s, padding-right 2s, color 2s;
}

footer a:hover,
a:active {
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  background-color: #20f4e7;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_menu">
  <p>
    here is my nav menu wich can close and open and has a form
  </p>
</div>
<div id="mapcontainer">
  <p>
    here will be a map
  </p>
</div>
<footer>
  <nav>
    <ul class="importantlinks">
      <li><a href="#">here is my footer</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

Comment: In your case it's not the map that take the remaining space but the `nav`.

Comment: @johannchopin if you will open fullscreen example you will see that map take all free space. I've just copied styles from the question!